# Function to measure size of a binary tree

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, syntax-error, binary-tree

When i tried to `size (N a (left a) (right a))` instead of `size (N a left right)`, i was told by ghci that this line conflicts when the definition. I am not sure why because in my data signature, it is `N a (Tree a) (Tree a)`. `size` is a function to count the number of nodes in a bin tree.

```
data Tree a = Nil | N a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)


size :: Tree Int -> Int
size Nil = 0
size (N _ left right) = 1 + size left + size right
```

Comment: `(N a left right)` is a pattern. `(N a (left a) (right a))` should also be a pattern, but it's an invalid pattern, and Haskell says ["Parse error in pattern: right"](https://tio.run/##RYy9CgIxEAb7PMVXJniC1x6cnYXNFeoLBLJeFmPUXFAQ3z3mR7Da2d1hrF4u5FxKRkeNUyCCxoiJHT6YMst2U38wFPjJfoY82turw4G06bB7KCEWfhOGoXX2PmK9LaPdS3PEpi2yth2dY20Hnm0hlY0eK1Snfn9cBSGumn1W7oFzvE/pCw), *not* what you said it says. You don't need to mention the type in the pattern, just use a variable to name the correspondent constituent of the data type.

Comment: Why did you limit `size` to only work on `Tree Int`?  It should be able to work on a `Tree` containing any type.  I.e. `size :: Tree a -> Int`

Answer (score 4):

> When i tried to size (N a (left a) (right a)) instead of size (N a left right)

`left` and `right` in this case are expressions of type `Tree Int`.

`a` is not a known variable or type in this context.

In case the definition is updated to `size (N a left right)`, then `a` is a bound expression of type `Int`.

Comment: "expressions" to the right of `=`, *pattern variables* to the left (leaving out the view patterns and the pattern guards with their more complicated rules).

Answer (score 1):

To help you see what’s going on, you could write your match internal nodes to name the left and right subtrees and their respective values with

```
size (N _ left@(N a _ _) right@(N b _ _)) = 1 + size left + size right
```

[Section 3.17.1 “Patterns”](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.17.1) describes what is happening with the at signs, which allow the programmer to name the left and right subtrees.

> Patterns of the form `var@pat` are called *as-patterns*, and allow one to use *var* as a name for the value being matched by *pat*.

The broad approach is inelegant for a number of reasons.

1. `left` and `right` are already constrained to be of type `Tree` because of the declaration of the `Tree` algebraic datatype.
2. Much worse, you’d also have to define the other three cases of `size` for either one or two `Nil` arguments.

[Section 3.17.2 Informal Semantics of Pattern Matching](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.17.2) outlines the cases for how the language handles patterns. Of especial note to you in the context of this question are

> 1. Matching the pattern *var* against a value *v* always succeeds and binds *var* to *v*.

and

> 5. Matching the pattern *con pat<sub>1</sub> … pat<sub>n</sub>* against a value, where *con* is a constructor defined by `data`, depends on the value:
>
> - If the value is of the form *con v<sub>1</sub> … v<sub>n</sub>*, sub-patterns are matched left-to-right against the components of the data value; if all matches succeed, the overall match succeeds; the first to fail or diverge causes the overall match to fail or diverge, respectively.
> - If the value is of the form *con′ v<sub>1</sub> … v<sub>n</sub>*, where *con* is a different constructor to *con′*, the match fails.
> - If the value is ⊥, the match diverges.

The first is how you want to do it and how you wrote it in your question, by binding the left and right subtree to variables. Your first attempt looked vaguely like binding to a constructor, and that’s why you got a syntax error.

Haskell pattern matching can be more sophisticated, *e.g.*, [view patterns](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns). For learning exercises, master the basics first.